# Super weird mouse behavior with xorg (awesome and sawfish wm)

Tags: xorg, awesome-wm

This issue drives me nuts: it's not completely reproducible but happens all the time. Sometimes when I move the mouse the screen so to speak goes back to the previous "frame" and shows me what was shown 1-2 seconds ago.

For example I open a new xterm, move the mouse and the xterm disappears, because about 1-2 seconds ago I didn't have the xterm open. Then move the mouse again and the xterm reappears as it should and then things are back to normal. I have no idea how to debug this. I tried sawfish wm also, and the same thing happens once in a while, but again it's not reproducible on purpose.

Another manifestation of the same problem: I switch to tag 1 with Mod-1 from tag 2, move the mouse and all the windows of tag 1 reappear again, but they are not functional (can't click inside them, can't type in them, etc), apparently I'm still on tag 1, but the windows from tag 2 are shown.

I'm completely lost on how to narrow down the problem and start debugging.